# file size is unexpectedly large

Tags: adobe-photoshop

i'm working over some artwork but the document size showing in the photoshop in the system i'm using is more than 1 GB. Although, the size of the PSD file is 33.6 mb. Due to this, photoshop is hanging and i'm not able to work properly over the artwork. i'm attaching the document size underneath.

[image]

i just want to know that why the photoshop is showing 1.17 GB?

Moreover, how can this problem be resolved?

Comment: The first number refers to the size of a one layer document, the second to the document with layers, filters, styles, masks, blends, channels and so on

Comment: Including unsaved states, history, caches...

Answer (score 1):

This could be due too that you have many layers. Merge layers and delete unused layers to reduce the size.

Comment: tried but when the same file is being opened in another system, it's showing other numbers but very less around 400-500mb something.

Comment: @joojaa Woops! Mis-read the question!

Answer (score 0):

you may check your image resolution from  Menu > Image > Image Size > Resolution.